# How to escape adb shell command line string in C#

Tags: c#, adb

I am struggling Escaping adb shell command line args in C# I have a command line that has to be sent as is to the EXE (ADB) to receive the exact response.
I am trying to Get IMEI number from the phone using ADB in C#.
I already have a working ADB Library just need to send the command as string.
This is what I am trying:

```
String cmd =  "adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1 | awk -F "'" '{print $2}' | sed '1 d' | tr -d '.' | awk '{print}' ORS=";
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
String cmd =  "adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1 | awk -F \"'\" '{print $2}' | sed '1 d' | tr -d '.' | awk '{print}' ORS=";
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `{print $2}`? Is `print` variable or string?

Comment: this is how its printed in adb shell

Comment: What does your standard output say?...are you sure the issue is commmand syntax?...what does your process call look like?...I'd expect to not see the adb part since that's not part of the arguments...how r u assigning the execution directory for adb?

Comment: That's a shell command sorry my bad not an command argument

Comment: just do the parsing in your `C#` code

Answer (score 1):

Put an @ sign in front

Update:

```
string str = @"""'{print $2}'";
```

Output:

> "'{print $2}'

```
string str2 = "\"'{print $2}'";
```

Output:

> "'{print $2}'

In short, you really have to use escape command for double quotes.

Update 2:

Don't pass string variable. Contain them in char array then pass it.

```
String cmd = "adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1 | awk -F \"'\" '{print $2}' | sed '1 d' | tr -d '.' | awk '{print}' ORS=";
char[] cmdChar = cmd.ToCharArray();
```

Then pass that cmdChar.

Comment: My bad, I just noticed you were trying to put double quotes within your string. If that's the case, double quotes really need an escape cmd since it's the indicator that you are passing a string. If you're using @ you'll have to use a single double quote to display a double quote, if not, what you did is ok.

Comment: If you use a string variables. The escape commands are embedded within it. Can you try passing a char array instead? `string` is just a collection of char anyway.

Comment: Passing a char array? while the library takes string as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a literal string (prefixed with an @) then you can have literal double quotes by repeating them.

So in your case you'd have:

```
String cmd = @"adb shell service call iphonesubinfo 1 | awk -F ""'"" '{print $2}' | sed '1 d' | tr -d '.' | awk '{print}' ORS=";
```

Comment: sed: unsupported command '

awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token

awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token

Comment: This is what I see when I use the command through cmd without c#
shell@cprimeltetmo:/ $ service call iphonesubinfo 1 | awk -F "'" '{print $2}' >
354335070938666        shell@cprimeltetmo:/ $

Comment: You need to show more of your code then so we can see how you're trying to run it.